# Can't locate object method "new" via package "MongoDB::MongoClient"

Tags: mongodb, perl

server - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

perl -MMongoDB -wle 'print for MongoDB->VERSION' - 0.45

db.version() - 2.0.6

```
my $dbh = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
```

How can i solve this problem without any upgrade on the server?

Method "connect" also doesn't work.

```
my $dbh = MongoDB::MongoClient->connect(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back then the function to connect was

```
$conn = MongoDB::Connection->new("host" => "localhost:27017");
```

Comment: You can browse the old documentation at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~mongodb/MongoDB/)